# Error when configuring clang compiler in vscode

Tags: c++, clang

I followed this website to configure my clang compiler [Using Clang in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)
When I click run the program it give me error
[problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSB9q.png)
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn6I6.png)
I believe I followed every step correctly. However, there is one step where my vscode displays different content compared to the tutorial

[step 3 in tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fDFa.png)
[options on my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zodMh.png)

Can someone provide some insight here? I tried google but it doesn't give me any relevant result.

Comment: For some reason, clang on Mac defaults to C++98. You must configure it for C++11 or later to use newer features.

Comment: @BoP do you know where to configure it? Should I do it in vscode?

Comment: Sorry, don't know the details. I don't use VSCode myself, just see this kind of question a couple of times a week. But yes, it involves fiddling with the json files.